# Passing non-primitive types when a link is clicked

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a very long list of objects that I want to display paginated. To do this I have tried the following:

```
@(data: Array[backend.scala.query.ResultListObject[backend.scala.datatypes.LineListObject]])

@import scala.util.Try

@for(dataItem <- Try(data.take(100)).getOrElse(data)) {
    <tr>@Html(dataItem.toHtml)</tr>
}
@if(data.length > 100) {
    <a href="@controllers.Application.moreData(data.drop(100))">next page</a>
}
```

The problem with this code is with the link for the next page. Of course, what I have there doesn't work because that isn't actually a route. So I tried this instead:

```
@if(data.length > 100) {
    <a href="@routes.Application.moreData(data.drop(100))">next page</a>
}
```

And in this case the routes file looks like this:

```
GET           /moreData:data      Application.moreData(data)
```

But this gives me a type error, because data is a string and I need a Array[ResultListObject[LineListObject]]. Although I could try to convert the data to a string and back, this is not possible, because the list is 10000 + items long.

How can I go about passing the rest of this data back to the same page using play 2.0?

Comment: So you want to pass 10000+ objects between two calls? I think you should put it to some storage (Db, cache, key-value, ...), no?

Comment: @cosmolev - Putting them in a database sounds like a good -albeit slow - idea. How much data can the cache hold?

Comment: It's limited by the RAM size of your server :) Max URL length is 2083 chars, and maximum cookies size is ~4Kb. So they are not an option you.

Comment: @cosmolev - I have implemented the solution successfully using the cache -- thanks

Comment: Cool! But keep in mind that cache never guarantees to return anything you've put there. So you should have a strategy for this case. Like repeating your initial DB-query in case cache returned null.